# Customizing QFileDialog directory combobox

Tags: pyqt, qfiledialog

When launching a PYQT QFileDialog the QComboBox for selecting the current directory is not the ideal widget in all scenarios.  I'm interested in replacing the QComboBox with a QLineEdit while keeping everything else the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your code look like?  Are you using the static QFileDialog methods?  They should use the native OS file/dir picker.  Are you trying to get a directory, save filename, or open filename.

Comment: I guess it cannot be done easily. You would probably have to modify Qt and PyQt for that.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a inherited class from QFileDialog and modify it like you want. Here are the documentation [QFileDialog](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html)

Answer (score -2):

To display a dialog the user to open a file:

```
objFile = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '/home/user',
                                          'My file (*.hello);; All File (*.*)'
                                     )
```

the parameter of `getOpenFileName` are: a title ("Open File"), the place of start loking for (could be `None`), and the diferent type file (this last is optional). This method returns str to de url of the file.

Comment: I'm not asking how to launch a QFileDialog rather how alter a portion of the UI and it's underlying behaviour.